# How to pass Fragment to a CustomArrayAdapter constructor

Tags: java, android

I have a MainActivity which has a Fragment named myFragment. I invoke the Fragment using a ViewPagerAdapter, which works fine.

I am trying to pass MyFragment to a CustomArrayAdapter but my application crashes at the constructor when it calls the super class.

Here is my code:

MyFragment.java

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements MyInterface {

    public MyFragment() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_paired_device, container, false);
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Row[] arrList = new Row[5];

        // THE FOLLOWING LINE IS SUPPOSED TO PASS THE FRAGMENT
        CustomAdapter myCustomAdapter = new CustomAdapter((MyInterface) this.getActivity(), arrList);
    }
}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Row> {
    Row[] rowItems = null;
    MyInterface myFragment;

    public CustomAdapter(MyInterface myFragment, Row[] resource) {
        // THE FOLLOWING LINE THROWS AN ERROR
        super((FragmentActivity) myFragment, R.layout.row_with_cb, resource);
        this.rowItems = resource;
        this.myFragment = myFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: MainActivity cannot be cast to MyInterface
```

For some reason, this.getActivity is supposed to send FragmentActivity but it sends the MainActivity.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: pass `this` instead of `(MyInterface) this.getActivity()` to adapter

Comment: Does `MainActivity` extend `FragmentActivity`?

Comment: Thanks @shayanpourvatan

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to pass MyFragment to a CustomArrayAdapter but my
>   application crashes at the constructor when it calls the super class.

You are currently trying to pass the `Activity` that `MyFragment` is attached to, not the `Fragment` itself:

```
CustomAdapter myCustomAdapter = new CustomAdapter((MyInterface) this.getActivity(), arrList);
```

The reason you are receiving a `ClassCastException` is because you attempting to "cast" the `Activity` returned by the `getActivity()` method call (which is in this case `MainActivity`) to `(MyInterface)`. As `MainActivity` does not implement `MyInterface`, this results in the exception.

It's actually unclear what you're attempting to achieve. As Eugen pointed out in his answer, the default `ArrayAdapter` constructor takes a `Context` argument. Neither `MyInterface` nor `MyFragment` are examples of `Context`s. Your `Activity` however, *is* a `Context`. So the following super call does not make sense:

```
public CustomAdapter(MyInterface myFragment, Row[] resource) {
    super((FragmentActivity) myFragment, R.layout.row_with_cb, resource);
}
```

Thus, you should be passing your `Activity` here. If you would still like to pass an `Interface`, then you could adjust your Constructor to something like:

```
private MyInterface myInterface;    

public CustomAdapter(Context context, Row[] rows, MyInterface myInterface){
    super(context, R.layout.row_with_cb, rows);
    this.myInterface = myInterface;
}
```

I'm not certain whether you actually want to pass your `Fragment` or `MyInterface` to your adapter from your question however.

Answer (score 0):

Array adapter requires just context (not fragment).

Change it to next:

```
public CustomAdapter(Context context, Row[] resource) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_with_cb, resource);
        ...
}
```

And remove casting of activity:

```
CustomAdapter myCustomAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this.getActivity(), arrList);
```

Answer (score 0):

The scenario that am trying to achieve is a little more complicated than the question itself.

I fixed it by passing this and this.getContext() to the CustomAdapter constructor. As Shayan and PPartisan mentioned, just a Context was enough to be sent to the ArrayAdapter constructor.

From the Fragment's perspective, this.getActivity() is expected to yield the current Fragment's 'FragmentActivity' (not sure if it should be MainActivity), which is a valid argument for the CustomAdapter's super class, but it does not return that(am still not sure why this happens). This is the reason why I was trying to do the cast.

The reason I need the fragment itself is because, I have a callback method (inside the CustomAdapter) which calls a method declared by myInterface and implemented by the Fragment.

For now, all is well.

Thanks